# Simple NSDateFormatter / String Parse

Tags: iphone, xcode, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
2012-10-12 19:29:43
```

Aquivalent `NSDateFormatter`:

```
[_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

Throws an exception ... Why?

Thank you!

**Reference:** http://waracle.net/mobile/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/

**UPDATE:**

The problem seems to be the string. If I hardcode the string:

```
NSString * string = @"2012-10-12 19:29:43";
```

It works fine.

I read it from an array of key-value pairs so I do:

```
NSString * string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", (NSString *)[[NSArray readFromPlistFile:@"latestchangesdates"] valueForKey:@"newsLastEdited"]];
```

**Console Output:**

*#1:*

```
2012-10-12 10:16:49
```

*#2:*

```
( "2012-10-12 10:16:49" )
```

*I think the problem is something which has to do with the string parse from the array.*

**UPDATE 2:**

```
[[[NSArray readFromPlistFile:@"latestchangesdates"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"newsLastEdited"]]
```

... finally did it.

Comment: Wat is the exception shown ??

Comment: What do you mean? `Thread 6: Signal SIGABRT` ? `'-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89a8170'`

Comment: ... hm, seems to be legit. Works if do not set the string dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[[NSArray readFromPlistFile:@"latestchangesdates"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"newsLastEdited"]]
```

... finally did it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the key `newsLastEdited` in your Plist file is actually returning an array not a string.

The line:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", (NSString *)[[NSArray readFromPlistFile:@"latestchangesdates"] valueForKey:@"newsLastEdited"]];
```

is simply casting to an `NSString` the returned value from `[[NSArray readFromPlistFile:@"latestchangesdates"] valueForKey:@"newsLastEdited"]`.  This does not automatically make the returned value a string.

What happens if you use the following instead:

```
NSString *string = [[[NSArray readFromPlistFile:@"latestchangesdates"] valueForKey:@"newsLastEdited"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

If I'm correct, this will take the first element of the array returned from the Plist `newsLastEdited` key.  If this works then you should probably take some time to understand the data structure stored in the Plist file.